# proper redirect taking into consideration http vs https

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

This seems to be such a standard question, but I am not able to find the answer anywhere. I am trying to solve the famous `.htaccess` redirect.

I have tried / modified / tested a good number of the available solutions online but they either don't work or don't do what I need.

Here is the latest one that I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This seems to work fine if I try to go from `example.com` to `www.example.com`. But `example.com/test/test.html` redirects to `www.example.com/test.html`! What? :-(

**The redirect policy I am looking for** - notice the difference between `http` and `https`

- `http://example.com` --> `http://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com/test/test.html` --> `http://www.example.com/test/test.html`
- `https://example.com` --> `https://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com/test/test.html?a=b` --> `https://www.example.com/test/test.html?a=b`

Comment: Do you want to serve HTTP and HTTPS? I suggest that if you are using HTTPS and have a certificate, that you make your life simpler and redirect all to HTTPS as part of what you are trying to do. Does that sound acceptable to you?

Comment: @closetnoc My plan was to serve both. I do have a certificate and I could implement a https-only environment. There are some minor points why this would not be desirable, so if both protocols are possible that would be my preferred choice.

Comment: Might this answer work?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way

Comment: I am sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I added an answer and will work with you if this does not work as you intend.

Comment: @Max Yes! This works! Thanks a million for finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of Max and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way), I found the answer to my problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You will have one problem that you will need to address so I will cover it first.

You will have trouble with duplicate content using the method you suggest. On each page, you can have either HTTP point to HTTPS content or the other way around. Adding this to the header of each page, obviously modifying the example URL on a case by case basis, then you should be fine.

For HTTPS pointing to HTTP:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/cake/blue-berry-ring-cakes-rock" />
```

-- or --

For HTTP pointing to HTTPS:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/cake/blue-berry-ring-cakes-rock" />
```

I think the following should work for you. I modified it from another answer that worked okay. If there is a problem, we can look at it again.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks closetnoc. I tried that on my server but it doesn't do the trick. The behavior I have is:
    `https://example.com/test/test.html` --> `https://www.example.com/test.html` (wrong redirect), 
    `https://www.example.com/test/test.html` --> `https://www.example.com/test/test.html` (no redirect),
    `http://example.com/test/test.html` --> `http://www.example.com/test.html` (wrong redirect),
    `http://www.example.com/test/test.html` --> page does not open at all, browser keeps loading.

Comment: Just tried another browser for this (the above was Firefox). I used Opera and there I have the same result, except for the last one. In Opera it does open. Not sure why Firefox won't open it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I found the answer and posted it.